# How to calculate the total sum of the multiplication table

Tags: c

I have generated the table and want to find the total sum of the table.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int no, i, mult, sum;

    printf("Enter the number you wish to multiply: \n");
    scanf("%d", &no);

    printf("Enter how many times you want to multiply the number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &mult);

    printf("Multiplication is as follows: \n");

    for( i = 1; i <= mult; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d X %d = %d\n", no, i, i * no);
    }
}
```

How can I get the total sum of the overall table?

Comment: By adding every value to e.g. `sum` (after you suitably initialized it of course)?

Comment: What have you tried? This doesn't look like "sum of a table" code.

Comment: You have to save the result of `i*no` into sum and print it after the loop

Comment: Initialize `sum`  to 0. Then inside the loop add `i*no` to `sum` and print `sum` at the very end...

Comment: @Jabberwocky "You have to save the result of `i*no` AND ADD IT TO `sum` and print it after the loop" better?:D

Comment: @RoQuOTriX that's what I was writing. Read my comment closely again.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I understood the problem very well, thanks. I corrected my comment

Comment: @RoQuOTriX yes, now your comment says _exactly_ the same as mine...

Comment: the resulting value 'sum' could easily overflow.  Even the `i*no` would overflow if the resulting value is greater than 2gig.  Suggest checking for overflow and modifying the working values to be `long int` or even `long long int`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `sum = 0` in the beginning and then everytime you print a value add it to the sum.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  int no,i,mult,sum=0;

  printf("Enter the number you wish to multiply: \n");
  scanf("%d", &no);

  printf("Enter how many times you want to multiply the number: \n");
  scanf("%d", &mult);

  printf("Multiplication is as follows: \n");

  for(i = 1; i <= mult; i++)
  {
      printf("%d X %d = %d\n", no,i,i*no);
      sum = sum + i*no
  }
  printf("sum = %d", sum);
}
```

Comment: Consider the "performance" problem, because you calculate `i*no` twice per loop

Comment: @RoQuOTriX your compiler will take care of that problem, unless of course you're using an antiquated compiler.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I know, I just wanted to change their own code as little as possible. Also as @ Jabberwocky said it is not a problem in modern compilers

Comment: Just don't trust "modern compilers" too much - nowadays, programmers have a tendency to think that compilers can do magic. Had the printf call been a function taking any integer address as parameter, the compiler might have to assume that the function could have change the value of the variable. It will then not only be forced to re-read the variable, it will have to perform the calculation once more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps to understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  int no, i, mult, sum, tmp;

  printf("Enter the number you wish to multiply: \n");
  scanf("%d", &no);

  printf("Enter how many times you want to multiply the number: \n");
  scanf("%d", &mult);

  printf("Multiplication is as follows: \n");

  sum = 0;
  for(i = 1; i <= mult; i++)
  {
      tmp = i*no;
      printf("%d X %d = %d\n", no,i,tmp);
      sum += tmp;
  }

  printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `tmp` is absolutely not necessary.

Comment: @Jabberwocky How to print it without `tmp` without calculating twice?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX if it's calculated twice in the C code, it doesn't imply that the generated code will do the calculation twice. Modern compilers will optimize this automatically.

Comment: @Jabberwocky even the tmp gets optimized out, so why bothering? https://godbolt.org/z/z6sbqv

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the total sum of the overall table?

By initializing the variable `sum` that you already have declared (zero is usually a good start) and updating its value while calculating the products.

I took the liberty, in the code below, of adding some input checks and perform the calculation without any actual product, but that's immaterial to the matter of the question. Feel free to experiment it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BPiS4Cp59Rnuyqb9).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ask_int(const char *str);

int main(void)
{
    int number = ask_int("Enter the number you wish to multiply:");
    int mult = ask_int("Enter how many times you want to multiply the number:");

    puts("Multiplication is as follows:");

    int sum = 0;  // <--------------------------------------  Initialize the accumulator.

    for(int i = 1, tmp = number; i <= mult; ++i, tmp += number)
    {
        printf("%d X %d = %d\n", number, i, tmp);

        sum += tmp; // <------------------------------------- Update.
    }
    printf("sum = %d", sum);
}

int ask_int(const char *str)
{
    int number = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        puts(str);
        int ret = scanf("%d", &number);
        if ( ret == 1 )
            break;
        if ( ret == EOF )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unexpected end of input.\n");
            break;
        }
        puts("That's not a number.");
    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
   int i, num, sum;
   printf(" enter the number for which the table will be calculated");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   sum=0;

   for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
   {
     printf("\n %d*%d=%d", num, i, (num*i));
     sum= sum + num*i;
     (num*i)+num;
     printf("sum= %d", sum);
   }
 }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()   

{ int index=0, n, result, sum=0;
  printf("Enter the Number You wish to Get Multiply Table and the sum : ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (int index = 0; index <= n; index++)
   { result = index * n; 
     printf("The Result is : %d\n", result);
     sum = sum + result; }
   
     printf("The sum of Multiplication Table is : %d", sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: as a cherry on top please don't forget to add some description to your code.

Comment: as a cherry on top please don't forget to add some description to your code